# Cant get less to load properly

Tags: javascript, less

I've started building my webpage and I can't get less to load properly. It gives me this error:

[image]

This is my basic structure:

[image]

You can see I've loaded my style.less file before compiling it. I've downloaded the less.min.js file from here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/v2.5.3/dist/less.min.js

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file system is domainless, so all requests are "cross-domain". You need to run a server.

Easiest way is python:

Go into terminal, open your website directory. Type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

You could also use live-server

```
npm install live-server
```

Comment: I can't believe i didn't run it through wamp server I had installed. I'm so embarassed right now. Anyways thanks for the insight :)